# How to virtualize Windows 7 guest on a Windows 7 host?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtualization, sandbox

I've been using VirtualBox for a while to virtualize Ubuntu inside Windows 7. Now I'm wanting to make a Windows 7 guest sandbox inside a Windows 7 host to install experimental software and tweak settings without fear of crashing my primary OS.

Before giving this a try, I wanted to know if it is possible and even legal under Microsoft's terms?

Secondly, is there a better (free) way to make a sandbox for the same purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Virtualizing Windows 7 in VirtualBox under Windows is exactly like Virtualizing it under Ubuntu, no tutorials required.

2) Yes it's legal *if* you have a valid license for the OS. Microsoft's legal terms don't allow you to use the OS, even in a virtual environment, without a license :/

Windows 7 has [XP mode built in](https://superuser.com/q/68354/13559) (Microsoft's Virtual PC integrated), and allows you to run XP for free, but it isn't 7 so it doesn't match your reqs. You can [read more about this here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/).

There isn't a better way, VBox rocks on Win and *nix!

**Note from the MS [licensing doc](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/virtualization.aspx):**

> Customers may install unlimited copies
>   of the software on the licensed
>   device. However, at any one time, they
>   may run no more than one instance
>   directly on the physical hardware

([html version avail here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Y7SMnuyaY9QJ:download.microsoft.com/download/3/d/4/3d42bdc2-6725-4b29-b75a-a5b04179958b/licensing_windows7_with_VM_technologies.docx+run+multiple+VMs+with+the+same+windows+license&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=za))

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted to know. And yes, I have a fully licensed copy of Win7 Professional - just wanted to know if I could use the same copy on the same machine within VBox.

Comment: Microsoft had at one time publicly given permission to use up to 3 VMs of the same Windows version as is installed on the host. This is still a gray area, but in general this practice is totally legal.

Comment: To clarify what wez wrote, XP Mode is only free with Win7 Professional and Ultimate.  Home does not come with XP Mode.  Otherwise, good answer.

Comment: @CarlF thanks for pointing that out! It seems that you can run multiple VM's with the same license, as long as you don't run them simultaneously. Check the link I added above :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a full walkthrough on running Windows 7 in VirtualBox that I've used before.  It is located [here](http://www.w7forums.com/run-windows-7-virtualbox-t107.html).

There is also [documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) on the VirtualBox website showing a list of supported guest OS's that can be hosted in VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks I actually found both of these same resources in my search, but neither of them specifically address Win7 host with a Win7 guest. Still, they're useful for helping me setup my machine now.

Comment: Don't see that the host makes much of a difference, but I guess you're right that the walkthrough is host-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a free way if you have the OS and license. You can you VMware. VMware has a program called VMWare Player, which can be found at the following link http://downloads.vmware.com/d/info/desktop_downloads/vmware_player/3_0. This tool is very easy to use. You may then create a virtual machine that probably very similar to VirtualBox. Try it out. It's free for the program, and very easy to use.

Good Luck-